# C# COM Interop interface wrapper with strange signature, UserId array pointer as ref UserId

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I'm trying to call a COM interface through a (badly written?) C# wrapper. I find the method signature in the wrapper a bit strange.

Unmanaged COM signature:

```
HRESULT GetUserRoles(
    [in] long size,
    [in,out, unique] UserRoleId* pUserRoles,
    [out, retval] long* pCount)
```

Managed signature from vendors COM wrapper:

```
int GetUserRoles(int size, ref UserRoleId pUserRoles)
```

It works as expected when i pass size = 1, pUserRoles is filled and 1 is returned. But how do I get all the user roles?

Calling GetUserRoles(5, ref pUserRoles) returns 3 since the user I'm testing with have 3
UserRoles, but I can only access the first one in pUserRoles

Is it possible to allocate an IntPtr as an array of UserRoleId and pass it as an argument to the wrapper function in any way?

I use a lot of other parts of the wrapper API and would not like to rewrite it myself. In an other case the out argument in the wrapper is an IntPtr and I've managed to get that working using GCHandle/IntPtr. Thought this would be possible to solve in a similar way but i don't know how to pass an IntPtr to a function expecting a UserRoleId ref.

Comment: This COM server isn't designed very well, the 2nd argument is actually an array.  No way for the type library to tell that it is, it assumes a simple variable passed by reference.  Workaround is described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8839826/17034).

Comment: I'm wondering if a viable solution would be to write a little CLI/C++ stub to use instead of the interop wrapper? Maybe you wouldn't even need to replace the whole interop wrapper, use it for everything except the bit that's incorrect and your CLI/C++ stub for the bit that doesn't work?

Comment: You should maybe ignore what I wrote in my previous comment. Hans Passant has indicated on the other thread that it may be possible but is probably even messier than the solution he suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will check out the workaround. Modifying IL asm seems a bit scary thou. Any hints a good place to read up a bit on this?